# Wpf Nesting Databound TabControls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty new to WPF and I'm trying to get a series of nested TabControls in order to filter some data, but the nested tabs never seem to want to appear.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Years}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedYear, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                 <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                           <!-- Data filtered by year and customer here -->
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

If I use defined TabItems without databinding within the first DataTemplate, they show up no problem. Is there a trick to getting nested databound tab controls to work? Am I doing this in a really dumb way in general?

Edit:
The data in my ViewModel this is meant to filter is an ObservableCollection of Forecast objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<Forecast> ForecastsNational
    {
        get { return _forecastsNational ?? (_forecastsNational = new ObservableCollection<Forecast>()); }
        set { Set(() => ForecastsNational, ref _forecastsNational, value); }
    }
```

Relevant properties being: 
    DateTime ForecastDate, 
    string CustomerName, 
    int Quantity, 
    decimal Amount

Currently, my "Years" and "Customers" collections are just being populated by selecting the distinct values from the ForecastsNational collection:

```
ForecastsNational.Select(x => x.Customer).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct()
```

My plan was to use an ICollectionView on the collection and apply filters using the SelectedYear and SelectedCustomer values:

```
ForecastsNationalCollectionView.Filter =
            m => ((Forecast)m).Year == int.Parse(SelectedYear) && ((Forecast)m).Customer == SelectedNationalCustomer;
```

Comment: show your ViewModel. unless the `Years` collection contains items of a class that has a `Customers` property, this won't work. If your ViewModel is "flat" then you'll have to use `RelativeSource` to make this work.

Comment: @HighCore right now the Years and Customers collections are simply collections of strings as a first attempt to get the tab headers I wanted. Is there a way to bind to my ObservableCollection of actual objects that this is meant to filter but only show the distinct values of the years and customers for TabItem header purposes?

Comment: instead of that, I'd just lookup the DataContext for the content inside the DataTemplate using a RelativeSource binding... it'd be much easier. Can you post the relevant viewmodel code?

Comment: @HighCore Updated with some viewmodel code

Comment: @HighCore I see what you mean now with RelativeSource.  The DataContext available within my DataTemplate is basically the "Year" object, which is just a string. By using RelativeSource to get my DataContext back to my ViewModel I'm able to bind to the collection like I was expecting.  Again, I'm new to WPF and XAML in general, but is there any way to make this less verbose? Seems like a lot of markup just to bind to the same thing a few times

Comment: the TabControl isn't really intended for what you're doing here, so you'll require extra XAML to make it work for your use case. Alternatively, simply use a couple of `ListBox`es and style their items to look like TabItems (or something like that). IMO, your current solution is the simplest one.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks again.  If you want to toss your comments in as an answer, it's yours.